# COM+ app not continuing until some unknown condition

Tags: mfc, com+

I have a COM+ application which I instantiate with

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TheComponent, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ITheComponent, &m_TheComponent);
```

This is followed by event initialization

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TransientSubscription,NULL,CLSCTX_ALL,IID_ITransinetSubscription,&Trans);
...some more code that eventually registers some CLSID_Events, IID__IEvents.
```

I have an MFC application with following:

```
OnBtn1Clicked()
{
  m_TheComponent->DoSomething();
}
```

also in the Dialog class there is

```
class CMFCMyDialog : public CDialogEx, _IEvents
{
  ...
  virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnSomething(); // abstract in _IEvents
```

When running, after clicking Btn1 two things happen: 1.`OnSomething()` is fired, and 2. the COM+ does a bunch of other stuff it should do. So far so good.

The interesting thing is that 1 & 2 happen *only after* `OnBtn1Clicked()` is exited. Even if i put a `sleep()` after `DoSomething()` or if I attempt to call `DoSomething()` within a different thread, 1 + 2 don't happen only after `OnBtn1Clicked()` is cleared.

From The COM component log I see it reaches and enters it's `OnSomething()` call but does not exist it (and of course does not reach the client side sink) until `OnBtn1Clicked()` is cleared. Once cleared, the sink is reached and the COM component continues execution.

All this would not be a problem since I can wait for after the button is clicked, but I need to implement this in a console application client. When implementing in a console application I was not able to make 1 and/or 2 happen. Only after I kill the client process (**!**) 2 happens (the COM+ continues processing) but of course client side `OnSomething()` does not since the process is dead.

Any idea what happens when `OnBtn1Clicked()` is cleared that affects the COM+?

Comment: Sounds like this is running in an STA. All method calls to COM objects in an STA are synchronized with the message queue. This requires that you keep dispatching messages for method calls to be executed, which you aren't while your code is in a message handler (`OnBtn1Clicked`). See [Processes, Threads, and Apartments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/processes--threads--and-apartments).

Comment: (see my edit) How can I release the message queue from within a console application?

Comment: There is no difference. You dispatch messages in a console application the same way you dispatch messages in a GUI application.

Comment: understood, but the message queue is "stuck" until client terminates. dispatching more message will probably not release it. I guess MFC has some method that "releases" the queue or "dispatches" the previous message.

Comment: MFC implements a (regular) [message loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues#creating-a-message-loop). Your console application needs to do the same on its STA COM threads. Difficult to suggest anything more substantial without seeing any code (or even getting an answer as to whether the affected COM object lives in an STA).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyConsoleClass::MyConsoleClass()
{
    new thread(&MyConsoleClass::Run, this);
}

void MyConsoleClass::Run()
{
    m_ThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
    m_IsActive = true;
    MSG msg;
    BOOL bRet;
    while (m_IsActive)
    {
        if (bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) != 0)
        {
            if (bRet == -1)
                // error
            else if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                m_IsActive = false;
            else if (msg.message == DO_SOMETHING)
                DoSomething(msg.wParam);
            else
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
    }
}

void MyConsoleClass::Invoke(const actionEnum action, const void *params)
{
    PostThreadMessage(m_ThreadId, action, (WPARAM)params, NULL);
}
```